# What AWS permissions are required to add/remove EC2 from an EC2 Target Group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

Hi I am new to AWS management, and I've been tasked with creating a role that grants the ability to add and remove EC2 from specific target groups. However, when looking at the the available rights that I can delegate to a policy, I do not see anything related to Target groups for any write "ec2:privilege".

This role is going to be assumed by another team.

Is this something I can delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't see that permission on EC2 policy becasue the policy for modify TargetGroups is in ELB v2.

You have two ways.

1. Create a group with policy EC2 full access associated and then create a user with that group associated. (low security because you allow a lot of permissions).
2. Create a group with policy ELB v2 with the permission ModifyTargetGroup in all resources and then create a user with that group associated. (In the object ELB v2 you can see all the permissions related to target groups... add, delete, modify etc).

Answer (score 2):

The other team would need these permissions:

- `elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets`
- `elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets`

You can limit the permissions such that they can only modify that specific target group.